# Arraylist random coordinates

Tags: arraylist

i am new to java and i need to make an array list that stores random coordinates..anyone help? is this right what i am doing?   i want to store alot of coordinates so that i can use them later on.. but not 100% on how to add them to the list..

```
ArrayList<Point> coordinates = new ArrayList<Point>();
        for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {   
            Random x = new Random();
            Random y = new Random();
            coordinates.add(x,y)
        }
```

Comment: What is `Point`? `java.awt.point` or a class of your own?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you use `Random`, or `ArrayList`. Read the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of coding blindly! You aren't really going to get anywhere by guesswork.

If you're using `java.awt.Point` (or another class that takes two ints as co-ordinates), this should work for you:

```
ArrayList<Point> coordinates = new ArrayList<Point>();
Random rand = new Random();
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {    
    int x = rand.nextInt();
    int y = rand.nextInt();
    coordinates.add(new Point(x,y));
}
```

Or more concisely, you can just do this inside the loop:

```
coordinates.add(new Point(rand.nextInt(), rand.nextInt()));
```

Note however, that `Random.nextInt()` results in a random integer from the entire value range of integers, which is fairly large. Change the `nextInt()` calls appropriately (refer to the JavaDoc) if you need to limit the range.

Answer (score 0):

`Random` is a class that generates random numbers. This doesn't mean that each `Random` instance is a random number. The standard way of using `Random` is:

```
Random rand = new Random();
<XXX> val = rand.nextXXX(); // XXX can be one of int, long, double, float, boolean, byte
<YYY> anotherVal = rand.nextYYY();
//do something with val and anotherVal
```

First, you should define what are the value ranges you want the random values to be contained in.

You should check the [Javadoc of Random class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) in order to get a better view.